# How to give a logical reason for choosing a model

Tags: machine-learning

I used machine learning to train depression related sentences. And it was LinearSVC that performed best. In addition to LinearSVC, I experimented with MultinomialNB and LogisticRegression, and I chose the model with the highest accuracy among the three. By the way, what I want to do is to be able to think in advance which model will fit, like ml_map provided by Scikit-learn. Where can I get this information? I searched a few papers, but couldn't find anything that contained more detailed information other than that SVM was suitable for text classification. How do I study to get prior knowledge like this ml_map?
[image: ml_map]

Comment: The performance of any classifier is highly dependent on the task at hand (e.g. Pedestrian recognition, Tumor classification), so you can't really generalize it. Also for any task there may be a group that outperformed a task which was previosly solved best by classifier *A* using classifier *B*. Best you can do is read recent publications/rewievs regarding ML about the topic you are currently working with and see which one is **currently** the best performing model.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the map. Not saying that there is no reasoning behind it but this is like ML algorithms 101 "use this is you have no clue" and it is omitting some very important parts - Neural Networks (+transfer learning), Gradient Boosted Machines, and ensembling in general - the techniques that usually work the best for most datasets. You can't know which algorithm will work the best unless you (or someone else) have already solved a very similar problem. - No free lunch theorem.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I study to get prior knowledge like this ml_map?

Try to work with different [example datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/overview) on different data types by using different algorithms. There are hundreds to be explored. Once you get the good grasp of how they work, it will become more clear. And do not forget to try googling something like *advantages of algorithm X*, it helps a lot.

**And here are my thoughts**, I think I used to ask such questions before and I hope it can help if you are struggling: The more you work on different Machine Learning models for a specific problem, you will soon realize that data and `feature engineering` play the more important parts than the algorithms themselves. The road map provided by `scikit-learn` gives you a good view of what group of algorithms to use to deal with certain types of data and that is a good start. The boundaries between them, however, are rather subtle. In other words, one problem can be solved by different approaches depending on how you organize and engineer your data.

To sum it up, in order to achieve a good out-of-sample (i.e., good generalization) performance while solving a problem, it is mandatory to look at the training/testing process with different setting combinations and be mindful with your data (for example, answer this question: does it cover most samples in terms of distribution in the wild or just a portion of it?)